# How do I calculate the area of a function if I follow its gradient?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

There is a function:

$f: \mathbb{R}^{n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R},\, f(\vec{v}) \in (-\infty
,a], a \in \mathbb{R},\, n > 0$

and I want to follow the gradient of this function $\nabla(f(\vec{v}))$ until I reach functions maximum. How do I calculate this line integral in general? What is the basic math behind?

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by the area you stretched?

Comment: Yes, I did not  know the exact word; basically just the area under the curve which was passed. How would you call it?

Comment: Perhaps you mean the length of the trajectory? I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: You walk on a bridge. While you walk you "stretch" a area to the bottom...

Comment: You mean a line integral?

Comment: Yes. (After wikipedia I am sure :D)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First write your problem as a gradient flow,

$$\dot{x}(t) = \nabla f (x(t))\\ x(0)=x_0$$

Then $x(t)$ is the trajectory you get by "following" the gradient to a maximum. If you want to find the "stretched" area you simply take the line integral of $f$ over the trajectory $x(t)$. Something like,

$$\int\limits_0^\infty f(x(t))|\dot{x}(t)|dt = \int\limits_0^\infty f(x(t))|\nabla f(x(t))|dt $$

Comment: Simply :) Thank you.

Comment: You can mark an answer as accepted by clicking the check mark next to the answer. This is helpful for future users who might have the same/similar questions.

Comment: I thought I did, sorry.